# Displaying table - vanilla JS equivalent

Tags: javascript, key-value

Example table contents:

- Shelf 1:      Item 12
- Shelf 2:      Item 11
- Shelf 3:      Item 10
- Shelf 4:      Item 09
- Shelf 5:      Item 08
- Shelf 6:      Item 07
- Shelf 7:      Item 06
- Shelf 8:      Item 05
- Shelf 9:      Item 04
- Shelf 10:     Item 03
- Shelf 11:     Item 02
- Shelf 12:     Item 01

  Display the shelf and item pairings by calling the following function:

  `displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);`

**CODE**

```
const displayShelfItemPair = (shelfName, itemName) => {

 return shelfName.map((shelf, item) => {
  return (
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{shelf.shelfName}</td>
      <td>{item.itemName}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  )
 })
}
```

What would/could be the JS equivalent? I want to display them in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do to output a `<table>` from a plain `JS` function.

```
function displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName){
    var table = '<table>';
    for(var i = 0; i < shelfName.length; i++)
        table += '<tr><td>' + shelfName[i] + '</td><td>' + itemName[i] + '</td></tr>';
    table += '</table>';
    return table;
}
```

You can put this table, say, in a `div` (with `id = "result"` in this case) like,

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);
```

```
<div id="result"></div>
```